# Are different t distributions generated by the same set of iid RVs independent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose $X_0,...X_n$ iid $\mathcal{L}(X_0)=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Define the t-distributions w/ n degrees of freedom:
$$Z_i:=\frac{\sqrt{n}X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{\underset{j\neq i}{j=0}}^nX_j^2}}$$
Are $\{Z_0,..,Z_n\}$ always independent? I would like to know a proof or in this case probably a counterexample. You are free to comment yes/no.

($n\geq 2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already see that the issue of the denominator excluding the term $X_i^2$ is not an impediment to showing dependence, since with a minor modification, $$Z_i^{-2} + \frac{1}{n} = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^n X_j^2}{n X_i^2}$$ implies $$\sum_{i=0}^n \left( Z_i^{-2} + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{-1} = n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Dependency: $\sum_{i=0}^n Z_i^2=n$  This shows the $Z_i$ cannot be independent.
A simple example $(n=1)$ then $Z_0^2+Z_1^2=1$.

Comment: Excuse me n=1 should have been excluded. I do not see the argument for $n\geq 2$ though.

Comment: Since the sum of the squares $=n$, they can't be independent.  Are you interested only in pairwise independence?

Comment: I don't think the argument can be applied though, because the denominator is different for each $Z_i$(note, that i is excluded from the sum), so $\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 \neq n$

Comment: I missed the fact that $j\ne i$ was part of the sum definition.  I revised what I would have given as an answer, but it is essentially the same as  that of heropup.